Cannot read properties of undefined in angular even after value is available in template and getting printed
There is featureImages section in component.html which is throwing this error not sure why it is happening
news-section.component.ts:296 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at NewsSectionComponent_div_1_div_4_div_1_Template (news-section.component.html:35:14)
    at ReactiveLViewConsumer.runInContext (core.mjs:10425:13)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:10968:22)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12489:13)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12653:9)
    at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12597:13)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12513:9)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:12653:9)
    at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12597:13)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12513:9)

Getting this error for a property when a user click on like button, but not on initial page load.
Also like button has a different function which is not related to initial page loading function
 featuredImages = [];
  featureNids = [];

  constructor(
    private restService: RestService,
    private gtmService: GtmService,
    private jsonApiService: JsonApiService,
    public hubService: HubDataService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    public router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStoriesToDisplay();
  }

  public getStoriesToDisplay() {
    // Try to pull from saved articles
    const index = this.newsFilterOptions.indexOf(this.currentOption);
    if (this.savedResults[index] && this.savedResults[index].length > 0) {
      this.storiesToDisplay = this.savedResults[index];
    } else {
      let restType;
      if (this.currentOption === 'Current') {
        restType = RestServiceType.GlobalNews;
      } else {
        restType = RestServiceType.GlobalNewsCategory + this.currentOption;
      }

      const responsePromise = this.restService.getPagedJsonApiContent(
        window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
        restType,
        this.amountToShow,
        0
      );

      responsePromise.then((resp) => {
        if (!resp.ok) {
          return Promise.reject(resp.statusText);
        } else {
          this.http
            .get('/get-featured-news-data?_format=json')
            .subscribe((res) => {
              if (Object.values(res)?.length > 0) {
                let sortedItemIds = Object.values(res);
                let splitedArray =
                  sortedItemIds[0]['field_top_featured_news'].split('+');
                splitedArray = [...new Set(splitedArray)];
                let topFeaturedNews: string = res[0]['field_top_featured_news'];
                this.http
                  .get(
                    '/get-featured-news-details-rev/' +
                      topFeaturedNews +
                      '?_format=json'
                  )
                  .subscribe((res) => {
                    if (Object.values(res['rows'])?.length > 0) {
                      const obj = {};
                      this.featuredImages = res['imagerows'];
                      console.log('this.featureImages', this.featuredImages);
                      Object.values(res['rows']).forEach((o: any) => {
                        obj[o.nid[0]['value']] = o;
                      });
                      // sorted according to added from back-end
                      let sortedFeaturedNewsList = splitedArray.map((e) =>
                        Object.assign({}, obj[e])
                      );
                      // remove the empty object if it is unpublished news
                      sortedFeaturedNewsList = sortedFeaturedNewsList.filter(
                        (value) => Object.keys(value).length !== 0
                      );
                      for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(res)[0]?.length; i++) {
                        this.featureNids.push(
                          Object.values(res)[0][i].nid[0]['value']
                        );
                      }
                      this.fnLoaded = true;
                      this.featurednewstoDisplay.push(sortedFeaturedNewsList);
                      this.featuredStoriesToDisplay =
                        this.featurednewstoDisplay[0];
                      console.log('this.featuredStoriesToDisplay', this.featuredStoriesToDisplay);
                      if (this.featuredStoriesToDisplay?.length > 0) {
                        let ids = this.featuredStoriesToDisplay
                          .map((a) => a.nid[0]['value'])
                          .map((i) => Number(i));
                        this.story(resp, index, ids);
                      } else {
                        this.story(resp, index);
                      }
                    } else {
                      this.story(resp, index);
                    }
                  });
              } else {
                this.story(resp, index);
              }
            });
        }
      });
    }
  }

Function called on like button
  toggleLike(userId: string, featurednews): void {
    if (featurednews && featurednews.nid) {
      if (this.isLikedBy(userId, featurednews.field_users_that_liked)) {
        // remove current user like
        let i = 0;
        while (i < featurednews.field_users_that_liked.length) {
          if (featurednews.field_users_that_liked[i].value === userId) {
            featurednews.field_users_that_liked.splice(i, 1);
          }
          i++;
        }
      } else {
        featurednews.field_users_that_liked.push({ value: userId });
      }
      // featurednews.nid = featurednews.nid[0].value;
      if (featurednews.nid[0] === undefined || featurednews.nid[0] === null) {
        featurednews.nid = featurednews.nid;
      } else {
        featurednews.nid = featurednews.nid[0].value;
      }

      let usersThatLiked = [];
      featurednews['field_users_that_liked'].forEach((element) => {
        usersThatLiked.push(element);
      });
      featurednews.usersThatLiked = usersThatLiked;
      this.restService.getRestSessionToken().subscribe((token) => {
        const requestBody = JSON.stringify(featurednews);
        this.restService
          .patchResource(
            `${RestServiceType.NodeData}${featurednews.nid}?_format=json`,

            requestBody,
            token
          )
          .subscribe();
      });
    }
  }


You can just use the TypeScript type safe check (?.) to prevent this undefined error from occurring. Best solution is for you debug the code and assess this failure and see if it needs to be fixed by adjusting the code.
featurednews.nid = featurednews?.nid?.[0]?.value;

From the looks of it nid is not having a zeroth value at its array index, or it might not be an array at all.
